# Tweepy Twitter Bot error 139 breaking out of loop

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So I am working on a Twitter bot to automate a professional project and I am running into an issue with the error handling in Python3.5 with the TweetPy package. In my code, I have a list of 10 Twitter profiles that I want to like and retweet their three most recent tweets, checking every hour for new tweets. Eventually, I'd like this list to potentially have dozens of accounts related to my local community. Understandably, I run into error code 139 frequently:

```
{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}
```

I expect this behavior and thought I had accounted for it with a try / except that should print the error code and them move on to the next tweet:

```
# Set up a loop to just keep going with a built-in sleep
while True:
# Cycle through important accounts and like recent tweets
redundant = 0
for acct in primeConnections:
    print("On account: {}".format(acct))
    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=acct, count=3, exclude_replies=True)
    count = 1
    for tweet in tweets:
        print("On count {} of 3".format(count))
        try:
            api.create_favorite(tweet.id)
            api.retweet(tweet.id)
            print("Tweet {} favorited and retweeted".format(tweet.id))
            time.sleep(3)
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print(e.reason)
            redundant += 1
            if '429' in str(e.reason):
                print("Sleeping 1 hour for rate limit - {}".format(datetime.now(tz=None)))
                time.sleep(6000)
        except StopIteration:
            print("Stopping Iteration")
            break
        count += 1
    if redundant >= 25:
        break

# Favorite any tweet we are mentioned in
tweets = api.mentions_timeline()
for tweet in tweets:
    tweet.favorite()

# When we reach the end of our cycle, sleep 1 hour
print("Cycle complete sleeping 1 hour")
time.sleep(3600)
```

The strange thing is that it works... right up until it doesn't.... here is the output I am getting where it makes it through 9 out of 10 Twitter handles, and then breaks on the 10th:

```
On account: [Username Redacted for Reasons]
On count 1 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On count 2 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On count 3 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On account: [Username Redacted for Reasons]
On count 1 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On count 2 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On count 3 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On account: [Username Redacted for Reasons]
On count 1 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On count 2 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On count 3 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On account: [Username Redacted for Reasons]
On count 1 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On count 2 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On count 3 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On account: [Username Redacted for Reasons]
On count 1 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On count 2 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On count 3 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On account: [Username Redacted for Reasons]
On count 1 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On count 2 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On account: [Username Redacted for Reasons]
On count 1 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On count 2 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On count 3 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On account: [Username Redacted for Reasons]
On count 1 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On count 2 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On count 3 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On account: [Username Redacted for Reasons]
On count 1 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On count 2 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On count 3 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
On account: [Username Redacted for Reasons]
On count 1 of 3
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tmac/Programing/Python Practice/./TBTBot.py", line 100, in <module>
    tweet.favorite()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/models.py", line 127, in favorite
    return self._api.create_favorite(self.id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 252, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 234, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
```

Any idea why this is breaking? Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: The call that's failing is not inside your `try`/`except` block.  It's the one in the short loop at the end of the code.

Comment: Hey Tim, I'm not sure that is the case as the code is failing while working on the 10th Twitter profile, and it appears to error out on the first of three tweets from that profile. I don't believe I ever make it to the simple for loop that is meant to like any tweet my profile is mentioned in.

Comment: I guarantee it is.  Look at the traceback.  The line that failed is `tweet.favorite()`.  You only have one such line in your code.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'll get that part re-written with a try/except of its own and keep working on this project. I appreciate the help!